# Subquery returned more than 1 value while inserting statement with multiple select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to run the insert statement with multiple select statements, I am getting error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,>, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

My query

```
insert into zzz_fkp_tbl2 (fname,lname) values
(
    (select top 20 percent [FNAME] from ZZZ_FKP_NEW_PATIENT order by newid())
    ,(select top 20 percent lname from ZZZ_FKP_NEW_PATIENT order by newid())
);
```

But when I run the insert statement with single statement, this query is runnig successfully, like:

```
insert into zzz_fkp_tbl2 (lname)
select top 20 percent lname from ZZZ_FKP_NEW_PATIENT order by newid();
```

Why I am getting error `Subquery returned more than 1 value` while using multiple select statements. But the insert statement is working fine with single select statement. How can I use multiple select statements in this case?
My requirement is to select separate random rows for fname and lname, but not together i.e. fname should be selected randomly and lname should be selected randomly.

target table

```
create table zzz_fkp_tbl2
(
    zzz_fkp_tbl2_id int identity(1,1) not null
    ,name varchar(200)
    ,fname varchar(200)
    ,lname varchar(200)
    ,gender int
    ,address int
    ,age varchar(10)
);
```

Comment: the problem is every time your sub query will fetch all the top 20 row values to insert into one column of the first row which is wrong approach

Comment: Do you want to keep fname/lname pairs together?

Comment: First one is a syntax you just invented. In TSQL this (first one) code means: tuple of two scalar values, each selected by subquery.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My requirement is to select separate random rows for fname and lname, but not together.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for this

```
INSERT INTO zzz_fkp_tbl2
            (fname,
             lname)
SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT [FNAME],
                      lname
FROM   ZZZ_FKP_NEW_PATIENT
ORDER  BY Newid()
```

**Update :**

```
SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT a.FNAME,
                      b.lname
FROM   ZZZ_FKP_NEW_PATIENT
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 [FNAME] ZZZ_FKP_NEW_PATIENT
                    ORDER  BY Newid()) a ([FNAME])
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 lname ZZZ_FKP_NEW_PATIENT
                    ORDER  BY Newid()) b (lname)
```

Comment: Additional info now added: separate random rows for fname and lname, but not together.

Comment: @jarlh - Updated.. But I think answer can be improved if sample data and expected result is added

Comment: If ZZZ_FKP_NEW_PATIENT has 100 rows, OP's original attempt tried to insert 20 rows. This query will insert 2000 rows.

Comment: @jarlh - yep. fixed now

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into zzz_fkp_tbl2 (fname,lname) values
    (
        (select top(1)  [FNAME] from ZZZ_FKP_NEW_PATIENT order by newid())
        ,(select top(1) lname from ZZZ_FKP_NEW_PATIENT order by newid())
    );
```

Comment: Explain why this isn't supposed to raise same error as OP's attempt?

Comment: getting error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'percent'.`. Please verify.

Comment: @jarlh it will return only single value

Comment: please remove " 20 percent " @nischalinn